# Why does $("ul:first").find("li") work but $("ul")[0].find("li") doesn't work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

Does that mean `$("ul")[0]` is not a jQuery object because it works when I use `$($("ul")[0]).find("li")`, though it looks a little ugly.

Does anyone have ideas why `$("ul")[0]` can't be used to `find` directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right; a jQuery object acts as an extension of an array of DOM elements. If you access any of them by index, you get a raw DOM object, not another jQuery object. If you want to access a jQuery object for just one of the elements the object represents, use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('ul').eq(0).find('li')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're correct -- `$("ul")[0]` is not a jQuery object. It's a DOM node (an `HTMLUListElement`, to be precise).

The reason that `$($("ul")[0]).find("li")` works is that you can construct a jQuery object from a DOM node by passing it as a parameter to the `$` function. `$("<ul>")`, for instance, will make a `ul` node and wrap it in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$("ul:eq(0)")` or `$("ul").eq(0)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
$("ul").index(0);
```

or

```
$("ul").eq(0)


$("ul")[0] is a DOM element
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to use $("ul").eq(0) instead of $("ul")[0]

Comment: $("ul") never returns an array. It returns a stack of jQuery objects.